# How to convert E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8 to this format &#23433;&#20840; in PHP 5.1

Tags: php, mysql

I got a keyword var from an url like this:

```
search.php?keyword=%E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8
```

with `utf8` encoding. Then I want to convert the keyword to this format:

`&amp;#23433;&amp;#20840;`

So I can use it in MySQL/PHP/

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read a unicode url with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859038/how-do-i-read-a-unicode-url-with-php)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280200/convert-unicode-to-html-entities-hex

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($_GET['keyword'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
//&#23433;&#20840;
```

Answer (score 0):

First one is url encoded, and what you want are html entities.

```
$string  = urldecode('%E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8'); // == 安全
$string2 = htmlentities($string); // == &#x5B89;&#x5168;
$string3 = htmlspecialchars($string2); // == &amp;#x5B89;&amp;#x5168;
```

The one from your question is **double** encoded (`&` got converted to `&amp;`) which I assume is wrong.

`23433` is **decimal** and **equals** hexadecimal `x5B89`. Same for the second code. For the browser, it doesn't matter if it's decimal or hexadecimal.

If you really intend double encoding, use `htmlspecialchars($string);` on the above code.

Comment: There is no need to urldecode GET arguments.  PHP does this automatically.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#refsect1-function.urldecode-notes